# Set builder notation with $\land$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

Is it possible to rewrite set builder notation with conjunction $\land$?

For example,
$$y\in f(A)=\{f(x) \mid x\in A\} \\
​​\iff \exists\,y, y=f(x)\land x\in A$$

Comment: In the last line you mean maybe $\exists x$

Comment: @guestDiego Then would it be okay if it becomes $​​∃x, y \space \text{such that}\space y=f(x)∧x\in A$ or $​​∃x, y, \space y=f(x)∧x\in A$? Or is there any better notation?

Comment: buzzee: that is _not_ okay.  You need just the $\exists x$ because $y$ is an 'unbound' variable: it appears on the left without any sort of quantifier, so it needs to appear on the right in the same fashion.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki $y=f(x)$. Why $y$ is an unbound variable?

Comment: @buzzee your LHS of the equivalence you're writing is $y\in f(A)$ - this means that $y$ is 'free' in the formula (more abstractly, you've got a formula that has $y$ as a parameter of sorts; you can imagine writing it as $T(y,f,A)$ to indicate the three parameters that appear in it).  This means any term equivalent to it should have $y$, $f$, and $A$ as 'unbound' variables, and only those three.  So $\exists x$ s.t. $y=f(x)\wedge x\in A$ is a legitimate equivalence because the one additional variable there ($x$) is 'bound' by the $\exists$...

Comment: ...but $\exists x\exists y$ s.t. $y=f(x)\wedge x\in A$ is not because the new $\exists$ term also binds $y$ and so the free 'parameters' are $f$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second row is wrong.  Rather than
$$
(\exists y)\  y = f(x) \text{ and } x\in A
$$
It should say
$$
(\exists x)\  y = f(x) \text{ and } x\in A.
$$

Comment: So $y \in f(A)=\{f(x) \mid x\in A\} ​​\iff (\exists x)  y = f(x) \text{ and } x\in A.$ 
Then, how is $(\exists y)\  y = f(x) \text{ and } x\in A$ represented in set builder notation?

Comment: @buzzee : That statement could be written as $x \in X\cap(\operatorname{domain}(f))$.  But that's not exactly "set builder" notation. $\qquad$